# Server with high bandwidth + ftp connection impossible (CENTOS 7 + NGINX)

Tags: nginx, centos, streaming

I have a video streaming server using centos + nginx (1gbps port).

When all services are active it is impossible to connect to ftp. There is no bandwidth left for FTP. It prevents me from adding new files.

Is there any solution? Is it possible to allocate a bandwidth for FTP or SSH? (5MBPS is enough)

I already activated connection and download speed limits in nginx but it didn't help at all.

Pay for a CDN service is not an option.

Comment: you may use the other physical interface on your server and obtain a new ip address for the new interface, to access to your FTP service.Use Quality of Service (QoS) to prioritize traffic is another option.check wondershaper aswell